# Problems implementing Admops in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I try to implement a banner-Ad in my App. I tried to do it like this (https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=de#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk, https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner?hl=de)

This is a part of my AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-8724409258852440~2528XXXXXX"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
```

Now I get this Error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: de.zimmer.myapp, PID: 11441
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The
> com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID metadata must have a String
> value.
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7244)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID metadata must have a String
> value.
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzo.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.6.0:9)
> at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.6.0:3)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7239)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzo.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.6.0:6)
> at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.6.0:3) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7239) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
> I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11441 SIG: 9

I don't understand what I did wrong because I did it exactly as in the guide. Does somebody has an idea?

Comment: add code full AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I restored my project and after this it worked. Maybe this can help someone.